# How can I find out the address space of the BIOS chip?

Tags: memory, memory-address, bios, pch, chipset

I want to write to BIOS, I know that it is required to disable write protection and more things that can be founded on the PCH datasheet (intel's case).

If I want to write to BIOS, first I have to know the address space of it. I have looked for information on the internet, but I have found nothing.

Is there any place to look at for that information?